# Anaconda Navigator 1.10.0 - Missing maximize opportunity on Ubuntu 20 (Focal Fossa) after upgrade it from 1.9.x version

Tags: anaconda, window, conda, maximize-window

After succesfull upgrade Anaconda Navigator from version 1.9.x to 1.10.0, I missed the so called 'maximize window' opportunity in the right top section of window (only the 'minimize' and 'close' window opportunities exists.

It seems, all others are work perfectly inside Anaconda (I can run subsystems, like Jupyter notebook, Spyder, etc), except this. Is there any solution to resolve this issue ?

I'm on Ubuntu 20 (Focal Fossa).

Thanks in advance your response !